# Display date in Mon dd yyyy format

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting value of Date of birth from my API. i need to display that in 3 different text box like jan ,01 and 2000.

How do I try that in TS.

I have tried storing the date of birth field in Date variable. but it gives value like Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0500.
Instead of that i need three values 
Jan 01 and 2000.

I tried Date pipe which gives me date like Jan-01-2000.

```
 this.newDate=new Date(this.patient.dateOfbirth);
```

Comment: None of the [display formats available](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options) accomplished your goal? Because it looks like maybe you just haven't tried them yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show it in input fields, I would suggest you parse the date in the class itself like below and use it in input fields :

1. For year, you can do : `newDate.getFullYear()`
2. For month, create array of months names, like : `let monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', ..., 'Dec']`, get month-index from date and use that to get month name `monthNames[newDate.getMonth()]`
3. For date, `newDate.getDate()`

If you want to simply show date in HTML template, you can use [Angular Datepipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe), like below :

1. For year, `{{newDate | date:'yyyy'}}`
2. For month, `{{newDate | date:'MMM'}}`
3. For date, `{{newDate | date:'dd'}}`

Answer (score 0):

Check the Ionic DateTime component
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

You can do what you want like this:

Code

```
dateToShow : any;

this.newDate=new Date(this.patient.dateOfbirth);
dateToShow = newDate.toISOString();
```

Template

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="dateToShow"></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try pipes if its possible

There are some predefined, such as

'mediumDate': equivalent to 'MMM d, y' (Jun 15, 2015).
'longDate': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y' (June 15, 2015).
'fullDate': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y' (Monday, June 15, 2015)

Using: 
{{ dateObj | date:'mediumDate' }}

You can add costum pipe if the basic is not suitable for you.

{{ value | pipe:'args'}}

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: It's not an answer. You can't just provide a link to answer. Write some explanation there and add your link like a reference to more information.